# How to know if a Python type has a concept of order? What is a sequence, really?

Tags: python, types, sequences

It's blowing my mind a little bit that OrderedDict in Python is not a sequence type. It has a concept of order, but it's not a sequence.

The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) say

> There are seven sequence types: strings, Unicode strings, lists,
>   tuples, bytearrays, buffers, and xrange objects.
>
> For other containers see the built in dict and set classes, and the
>   collections module. ...Most sequence types support the following
>   operations....Sequence types also support comparisons.

Those operations corresponding to `__contains__`, `__add__` for concatenation, `__getitem__` with integers (in `range(len(foo))`), `__len__`, `__min__`, `__slice__`, `index` and `count`. `__lt__` etc implement comparisons.

OrderedDicts implement some of these methods but not others, probably because the syntactic sugar for accessing items by key (as in dict) or order (as in index) is the same.

I know if something implements `__iter__` I can loop through it. How can I definitely know if something has an order? I would have thought that is what is meant by "sequence", the nth item is always the nth item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a duck typing world, this is a difficult question.

Both [sequences and mapping](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) use `__getitem__()` to access items, using inter indexes and keys, respectively. Looking for the availability of the `__getitem__()` method does not tell them apart, you need to look at what the method actually does.

For the dict it is not possible to know whether the integer argument to `__getitem__()` is an index or a key, so it always works mapping-style.

Therefore, I think a dict is not a sequence at all, even though it supports iteration. Same applies to the set.

Looking at the `collections.abc.Sequence` base class may be the best test. For custom types, just make sure they are derived from this base class.

Answer (score 0):

[`issubclass(list, collections.abc.Sequence)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence)

Note this only works on built-in types.

Comment: I am definitely interested in custom types as well.

Comment: This works for user-defined types too, provided the author bothered making said type a (actual or virtual) subclass of `collections.abc.Sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that of indexing.
An example with lists:

```
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'][1]          # get element with index 1
'b'
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'].index('b')  # what is the (first) index of 'b'?
1
```

Now with strings:

```
>>> 'abc'[1]
'b'
>>> 'abc'.index('b')
1
```

Now with Ordered Dictionaries:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict(zip(['cat', 'dog'], ['meow', 'auuu']))
>>> od[1]
(...)
KeyError: 1
>>> od.index('dog')
AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'index'
```

So OrderedDict preserves the order the items are added, so that it can be iterated in the same order, but it's not possible to use an index on it.