# What exactly is a Sequence?

Tags: python, numpy, sequence

The Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) are a bit ambiguous

> sequence
>
> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a `__len__()`
> method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence
> types are list, str, tuple, and bytes. Note that dict also supports
> `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, but is considered a mapping rather than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary immutable keys rather than
> integers.
>
> The collections.abc.Sequence abstract base class defines a much richer interface that goes beyond just `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`,
> adding count(), index(), `__contains__()`, and `__reversed__()`. Types
> that implement this expanded interface can be registered explicitly
> using register().

In particular, using `abc.collections.Sequence` as the gold standard as [recommended by some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17522992/7207392) would mean that, for example, numpy arrays are not sequences:

```
isinstance(np.arange(6),collections.abc.Sequence)
# False
```

There is also something called the [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html) [Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43566044/7207392) but that appears to be exposed only at the C-API. There the criterion is

> int PySequence_Check(PyObject *o)
>
> Return 1 if the object provides sequence protocol, and 0 otherwise. Note that it returns 1 for Python classes with a
> `__getitem__()` method unless they are dict subclasses since in general case it is impossible to determine what the type of keys it supports.
> This function always succeeds.

Finally, I don't follow this new (-ish) type annotation business too closely but I would imagine this also would benefit from a clear concept of what a sequence is.

So my question has both a philosophical and a practical side: What exactly is a sequence? and How do I test whether something is a sequence or not? Ideally, in a way that makes numpy arrays sequences. And if I ever start annotating, how would I approach sequences?

Comment: In `numpy` code we see errors like "setting an array element with a sequence".  A list or tuple would raise that, but not a single element array.  `arr[0] = [1]` gives the error; `arr[0]=np.array([1])` does not.  `arr[0]=np.array([1,2])` does.

Comment: The practical answer is that a type matching Sequence requires active registration (via inheritance or Sequence.register) and definition of methods, and no one bothered to do that.

Comment: Mostly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566044/what-is-pythons-sequence-protocol

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm aware of that post and had in fact already referenced it. The annotation angle is new, though, and seems to me to add one more reason to seek clarity. Also,`.index` and `.count` are not mentioned in that thread, so I was wondering whether they are new and `collections.abc.Sequence` has inched two methods farther away from core/minimal sequence requirements.

Comment: For annotations, you're pretty much stuck using `typing.Sequence` or nothing. I recommend nothing, if you want to support NumPy arrays. The sequence-ness of a NumPy array isn't even fully determined by its type - 0-dimensional arrays don't support `len` or integer indices.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica 0D arrays are just an edge case we have to live with, not entirely unlike empty lists which also do not support integer indexing and are also generally quite good at punishing sloppy programming etc.

Comment: Not that it answers the core of the question, but, for practical purposes, if you want to use a type annotation specifically for sequences and NumPy arrays, you could also use [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union): `SequenceOrNdarray = Union[Sequence[Any], np.ndarray]`.

Answer (score 11):

## Brief introduction to typing in Python

Skip ahead if you know what structural typing, nominal typing and duck typing are.

I think much of the confusion arises from the fact that `typing` was a provisional module between versions 3.5 and 3.6. And was still subject to change between versions 3.7 and 3.8. This means there has been a lot of flux in how Python has sought to deal with typing through type annotations.

It also doesn't help that python is both duck-typed and nominally typed. That is, when accessing an attribute of an object, Python is duck-typed. The object will only be checked to see if it has an attribute at runtime, and only when immediately requested. However, Python also has nominal typing features (eg. `isinstance()`and `issubclass()`). Nominal typing is where one type is declared to be a subclass of another. This can be through inheritance, or with the `register()` method of `ABCMeta`.

`typing` originally introduced its types using the idea of nominal typing. As of 3.8 it is trying to allow for the more pythonic structural typing.
Structural typing is related to duck-typing, except that it is taken into consideration at "compile time" rather than runtime. For instance, when a linter is trying to detect possible type errors -- such as if you were to pass a `dict` to a function that only accepts sequences like tuples or list. With structural typing, a class `B` should be considered a subtype of `A` if it implements the all the methods of `A`, regardless of whether it has been declared to be a subtype of `A` (as in nominal typing).

## Answer

sequences (little s) are a duck type. A sequence is any ordered collection of objects that provides random access to its members. Specifically, if it defines `__len__` and `__getitem__` and uses integer indices between 0 and n-1 then it is a sequence. A Sequence (big s) is a nominal type. That is, to be a Sequence, a class must be declared as such, either by inheriting from Sequence or being registered as a subclass.

A numpy array *is* a sequence, but it *is not* a Sequence as it is not registered as a subclass of Sequence. Nor should it be, as it does not implement the full interface promised by Sequence (things like `count()` and `index()` are missing).

It sounds like you want is a **structured type** for a sequence (small s). As of 3.8 this is possible by using [protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544). Protocols define a set of methods which a class must implement to be considered a subclass of the protocol (a la structural typing).

```py
from typing import Protocol
import numpy as np

class MySequence(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def __contains__(self, item):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def __iter__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

def f(s: MySequence):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print(s[i], end=' ')
    print('end')

f([1, 2, 3, 4]) # should be fine
arr: np.ndarray = np.arange(5)
f(arr) # also fine
f({}) # might be considered fine! Depends on your type checker
```

Protocols are fairly new, so not all IDEs/type checkers might support them yet. The IDE I use, PyCharm, does. It doesn't like `f({})`, but it is happy to consider a numpy array a Sequence (big S) though (perhaps not ideal). You can enable runtime checking of protocols by using the `runtime_checkable` decorator of `typing`. Be warned, all this does is individually check that each of the Protocols methods can be found on the given object/class. As a result, it can become quite expensive if your protocol has a lot of methods.

Comment: Note that large-s sequence also is related to the *other* specification for small-s [Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range). Which codify the structural equivalent to nominal, large-s Sequence.

Comment: Related yes, but I think it's also presented as a convenience rather than a definitive definition. That is, it implements the shared set of functionality of the inbuilt sequence types, but is not presented as the defacto definition of a sequence. For instance, it doesn't implement `+` or `*` which are both listed as common operations implemented by sequences. My answer was to point out the laxness of the definition, and nudge towards a custom protocol where OP can define the spec which is required.

Comment: Could you enlarge on duck vs structural, please? I don't understand the difference. What does compile vs run time mean here?

Comment: Runtime means while the program is actually running. Compile time, is stuff that is run before the runtime. For C-like languages, this is primarily the compiler. For languages like Python, this is primarily linters. With respect to Python, structural typing only really has any impact on linters. Before running your code, the linter will try to detect possible type errors. Using Protocols tells the linter that we only care about whether the class implements the required methods and not its strict nominal type. That is, you care that a class behaves like a sequence, and not its nominal type.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the _"if it [...] uses integer indices between 0 and n-1 then it is a sequence"_ requirement? I wasn't able to find anything that actually specified that.

Comment: @Eric It's only required that `__getitem__` be implemented (and not be a subclass of dict) to be a sequence. But without the `0 <=i<n` part, certain features will break (`for x in seq` and `x in seq`). That is, if you don't define `__iter__` or `__contains__`, python has fallback strategies that rely on `0<=i<n`. See https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations and the note in https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__ It's called "old-style iteration protocol" in the docs. Don't rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most practical way to define a sequence in Python is 'A container that supports indexing with integers'.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) definition also holds:

> a sequence is an enumerated collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed and order does matter.

To validate if an object is a sequence, I would emulate the logic from the [Sequence Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Check):

```
hasattr(test_obj, "__getitem__") and not isinstance(test_obj, collections.abc.Mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the doc you pasted:

> The collections.abc.Sequence abstract base class defines a much richer interface that goes beyond just `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, adding `count()`, `index()`, `__contains__()`, and `__reversed__()`. Types that implement this expanded interface can be registered explicitly using register().

`numpy.ndarray` does not implement the `Sequence` protocol because it does not implement `count()` or `index()`:

```
>>> arr = numpy.arange(6)
>>> isinstance(arr, Sequence)
False
>>> arr.count(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'
>>> arr.index(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Contrast to a `range`:

```
>>> r = range(6)
>>> isinstance(r, Sequence)
True
>>> r.count(3)
1
>>> r.index(3)
3
```

If you want to claim that `arr` is a `Sequence` you can, by using the `register()` class method:

```
>>> Sequence.register(numpy.ndarray)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> isinstance(arr, Sequence)
True
```

but this is a lie, because it doesn't actually implement the protocol (the `register()` function doesn't actually check for that, it just trusts you):

```
>>> arr.count(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'
```

so doing this may lead to errors if you pass a `numpy.ndarray` to a function that expects a `Sequence`.

Comment: This doesn't really hold up. Most types registered with `collections.abc.Sequence` don't actually implement all the methods (especially `__reversed__`). Checking `issubclass(Whatever, collections.abc.Sequence)` really only checks if `Whatever` has `collections.abc.Sequence` in its MRO or if `Whatever` (or a superclass) is registered with `collections.abc.Sequence` (or a subclass). There is no interface check whatsoever.

Comment: Yes; I said this in my answer, but it's worth reiterating that **`Sequence.register` does not actually validate that you implement the protocol.**  If a module registers a class with `Sequence` that doesn't actually implement it, such that instances of the class do not behave the way `Sequence`s are supposed to behave, then **this is a lie** and it should be considered a bug in that module IMO.