# Typehinting function to accept numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, types, mypy

I'm having trouble understanding why mypy throws an error with the following example.

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Sequence


def compute(x: Sequence[float]) -> bool:
    # some computation that does not modify x
    ...


compute(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

Mypy Error:

```
Argument 1 to "compute" has incompatible type "ndarray[Any, dtype[floating[Any]]]"; expected "Sequence[float]"  [arg-type]
```

In particular, since [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) requires iterability, reversability, and indexing, I'd think a numpy array should also be a `Sequence`. Is it related to the fact that numpy arrays are mutable, and `Sequence` types are intended to be immutable? I notice when I change `Sequence` to `Iterable`, the problem is fixed. But I need to be able to index `x` in `compute`.

So, what is the best way to typehint the `compute` function so that it can accept objects with iterability and indexing?

Comment: Because `numpy.ndarray` objects do not conform to the `collections.abc.Sequence` ABC, which must be read-only, nor does it support `.index` and `.count` which are part of the interface.

Comment: why don't you just create your own protocol? one that requires `__iter__` and `__getitem__`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your first comment is misleading: `list` is compatible with `Sequence`, and it is not immutable. The implementation does not have to be immutable - it's just guaranteed only to have non-modifying methods. Nothing prevents you from adding modifying methods, they're just invisible/unusable as `Sequence` members. Only `index` and `count` make a trouble here.

Comment: @SUTerliakov yes, you are absolutely right if we are talking about type annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.ndarray` is not a `Sequence` (incompatible with corresponding protocol), because `np.ndarray` does not implement `.count` and `.index` methods, which [are required](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) for `collections.abc.Sequence`, see the table of methods in link.

Here's a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970581/what-exactly-is-a-sequence).

To make something sequence-like compatible with `np.ndarray`, I'd suggest to define your protocol:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Collection, Reversible, Iterator
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, overload

_T_co = TypeVar('_T_co', covariant=True)

class WeakSequence(Collection[_T_co], Reversible[_T_co], Protocol[_T_co]):
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> _T_co: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> WeakSequence[_T_co]: ...
    def __contains__(self, value: object) -> bool: ...
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[_T_co]: ...
    def __reversed__(self) -> Iterator[_T_co]: ...
```

This is basically the same as `Sequence` definition [in typeshed](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/typing.pyi#LL460C1-L473C51) except that I'm using `Protocol` instead of `Generic` (to avoid adding implementation - stubs don't have to, plus this makes structural subtyping more obvious) and omit `.index` and `.count` methods.

Now `np.ndarray` should be compatible with `WeakSequence` as well as a `list` or `tuple`, and you can use `WeakSequence` instead of `collections.abc.Sequence` in your annotations.

Comment: Ahhh okay I missed that it had to have `.count` and `.index` _methods_. I think index just meant that it supported indexing. I guess I missed the count requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using np.ndarray as the type hint for x. I checked `type(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))` and it returned np.ndarray

Comment: In other places I'd like to be able to call `compute` on variables that are not numpy arrays, however.